# Input Form Using Codeigniter and Bootstrap 3

Tags: forms, codeigniter, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using Codeigniter, styled with Bootstrap 3 to build a website.

I can't stylize the text-fields built by the PHP/Form Helper, as I'm not sure where to use the tags, every solution I've tried has resulted in either an extra text field, or just the addon appearing, or nothing at all.

**Controller**

```
public function __construct ()
{
    parent::__construct();
}

public function index ()
{
    // Fetch all users
    $this->data['users'] = $this->user_m->get();

    // Load view
    $this->data['subview'] = 'admin/user/index';
    $this->load->view('admin/_layout_main', $this->data);
}

public function edit ($id = NULL)
{
    // Fetch a user or set a new one
    if ($id) {
        $this->data['user'] = $this->user_m->get($id);
        count($this->data['user']) || $this->data['errors'][] = 'User could not be found';
    }
    else {
        $this->data['user'] = $this->user_m->get_new();
    }

    // Set up the form
    $rules = $this->user_m->rules_admin;
    $id || $rules['password']['rules'] .= '|required';
    $this->form_validation->set_rules($rules);

    // Process the form
    if ($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE) {
        $data = $this->user_m->array_from_post(array('name', 'email', 'password'));
        $data['password'] = $this->user_m->hash($data['password']);
        $this->user_m->save($data, $id);
        redirect('admin/user');
    }

    // Load the view
    $this->data['subview'] = 'admin/user/edit';
    $this->load->view('admin/_layout_main', $this->data);
}

public function delete ($id)
{
    $this->user_m->delete($id);
    redirect('admin/user');
}

public function login ()
{
    // Redirect a user if he's already logged in
    $dashboard = 'admin/dashboard';
    $this->user_m->loggedin() == FALSE || redirect($dashboard);

    // Set form
    $rules = $this->user_m->rules;
    $this->form_validation->set_rules($rules);

    // Process form
    if ($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE) {
        // We can login and redirect
        if ($this->user_m->login() == TRUE) {
            redirect($dashboard);
        }
        else {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('error', 'That email/password combination does not exist');
            redirect('admin/user/login', 'refresh');
        }
    }

    // Load view
    $this->data['subview'] = 'admin/user/login';
    $this->load->view('admin/_layout_modal', $this->data);
}

public function logout ()
{
    $this->user_m->logout();
    redirect('admin/user/login');
}

public function _unique_email ($str)
{
    // Do NOT validate if email already exists
    // UNLESS it's the email for the current user

    $id = $this->uri->segment(4);
    $this->db->where('email', $this->input->post('email'));
    !$id || $this->db->where('id !=', $id);
    $user = $this->user_m->get();

    if (count($user)) {
        $this->form_validation->set_message('_unique_email', '%s should be unique');
        return FALSE;
    }

    return TRUE;
  }
}
```

**View**

```
    <div class="modal-body">
<?php echo validation_errors(); ?>
<?php echo form_open();?>

<div class="container">
    <div class="modal-header">
    <h3>Log in</h3>
    <p>Please log in using your credentials</p>
</div>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <td>Email</td>
        <td><?php echo form_input('email'); ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Password</td>
        <td><?php echo form_password('password'); ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td><?php echo form_submit('submit', 'Log in', 'class="btn btn-primary"'); ?></td>
    </tr>
</table>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            &copy; <?php echo date('Y'); ?> <?php echo $meta_title; ?>
        </div>
<?php echo form_close();?>

    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

**Bootstrap**

```
      <form class="form-signin" role="form">
    <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Please sign in</h2>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="email" required autofocus value="<?php echo set_value('email') ?>">
    <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="password" required value"<?php echo set_value('password') ?>">
    <label class="checkbox">
      <input type="checkbox" value="remember-me"> Remember me
    </label>
    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Sign in</button>
  </form>
```

Comment: make sure you have added bootstrap at the header

Comment: you can write the normal form tags with bootstrap class here too,no worries

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You just pass everything as an array to form_input

```
<?php echo form_input(['name' => 'email', 'id' => 'email', 'class' => 'form-control', 'value' => set_value('email')]); ?>
```

Here's your entire form as presented,

```
<?php echo form_open('controller/method', ['class' => 'form-signin', 'role' => 'form']); ?>

<h2 class="form-signin-heading">Please sign in</h2>

<?php echo form_input(['name' => 'email', 'id' => 'email', 'class' => 'form-control', 'value' => set_value('email'), 'placeholder' => 'Email']); ?>

<?php echo form_password(['name' => 'password', 'id' => 'password', 'class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Password']); ?>

<label class="checkbox">
    <?php echo form_checkbox(['name' => 'remember_me', 'value' => 1]); ?>
</label>

<button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Sign in</button>

<?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @ahmad. now i can use CSS Bootstrap on my Codeigniter form action.