# Codeigniter form to Bootstrap

Tags: forms, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter

I had this form (works ok, I didn't made it, I just have to enhance it with Bootstrap).:

```
<?php
    echo form_open('panel/usuarios/recibirdatos');
    $nombre = array(
    'name' => 'nombre',
    'placeholder' => 'Escribe tu nombre',
    );
    $apellidop = array(
    'name' => 'apellidop',
    'placeholder' => 'Escribe tu apellido',
    );
    $sexo = array(
        'name' => 'sexo',
    );
    $region = array(
        'name' => 'region',
        'placeholder' => 'Selecciona region',
    );
    ?>
    <?php 
    echo form_label('Nombres: ','nombre');
    echo '&nbsp';
    echo form_input($nombre);

    echo form_label('Apellido Paterno: ','apellidop');
    echo '&nbsp';
    echo form_input($apellidop);

    echo form_label('Sexo: ');
    echo '&nbsp';
    echo    "<select name= 'sexo'>
            <option value='M' <?php echo set_select('M', 'Masculino', TRUE); ?> Masculino</option>
            <option value='F' <?php echo set_select('F', 'Femenino'); ?> Femenino</option>
            </select>";

    echo form_label('Región: ');
    echo '&nbsp';
    echo form_dropdown('countriesDrp', $countryDrop,'','class="required" id="countriesDrp"');
    echo form_label('Comuna: ');
    echo '&nbsp';
    echo '<select name="cityDrp" id="cityDrp"><option value="">Select</option></select>';
    echo form_label('Dirección: ','direccion');
    echo '&nbsp';
    echo form_input($direccion);
    echo form_label('Telefono: ','telefono');
    echo '&nbsp';
    echo form_input($telefono);
    echo '<br>';
    ?>
    <?php echo form_submit('','Enviar'); echo form_close();?>
```

Now I want to enhance it with Bootstrap, like this:

```
<form action="#" class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-2 control-label">Nombres</label>
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
        <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
     etc
    </div>
    etc...
    <div class="form-actions">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Save</button> or <a class="text-danger" href="#">Cancel</a>
    </div>
</form>
```

I'm not sure how to use the inputs of CI with Bootstrap, I was reading this [SOLVED - Input Form Using Codeigniter and Bootstrap 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20855009/input-form-using-codeigniter-and-bootstrap-3) but I can't make it. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add classes to your form inputs. e.g for first input

```
$nombre = array(
    'name' => 'nombre',
    'placeholder' => 'Escribe tu nombre',
    'class' => 'form-control',
); 
echo '<div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-2 control-label">'.form_label('Nombres: ','nombre').'</label>
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
          '.form_input($nombre).'
        </div>
      </div>';
```

This [link](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/form_helper.html) may be helpful for more information about Codeigniter forms.

Comment: Codeigniter doc's now here on codeIgniter website http://www.codeigniter.com/docs